# Как сделать резервную копию в winscp

Tags: windows, сервер, резервное-копирование, пароль

В программе winscp хранятся IP серверов, а также логины и пароли к ним. Как сделать бэкап этих данных? где они хранятся физически? В каком файлае не винчестере?

Comment: В своём профиле `winscp` искать пробовал?

Answer (score 2):

Есть два возможных хранилища.
Вы можете посмотреть настройки хранилища через: "Настройки=>Хранилище=>Хранилище конфигурации"
Если указано Реестр Windows, то нужно смотреть ветку
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2` и выгружать ее.

Если указан .ini файл, то он может храниться, как в папке с установленной программой, так и по пути `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\WinSCP.ini` 
ini файл просто переносится на новую систему.

Backup делает с помощью самой WinSCP - "Инструменты=>Экспорт/Сохранение настроек. Выгружается ini файл, который можно перенести и импортировать.